# Nginx 1.18.0 not executing php files, using php7.4-fpm

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx

Appologies in advance, this is rather a long description, skip to the **Problem** peice below for my actual problem, also see the **config files**

I'm setting up an set of internal web sites for where I work, I decided to use nginx as the main app I use (GitLab) uses it underneath. Although I now think that maybe that wasn't so sensible !).

I can get GitLab to function just fine. I have temporarily 'turned it off' so as I can get the entry point to the pages up an running.

**Background**
The plan.

To run a single page for entry, and then have the various 'apps' running on sub domains.

So out main server is called `reslab` and then we will have the `gitlab.reslab` running on a subdomain, and then any other items we need on other subdomains.

So we we plan to put all our documentation into a mediawiki, so that will live on `wiki.reslab`
Also we expect to run a test version of the units web site, which will reside on `testweb.reslab`. Eventually I expect more things to end up on here, such as sub sites for specific projects.

As the main site is running on WordPress, I decided that I would use wordpress as the principle development option for the all the pages that may be created.

The **problem**

Whenever I open a link that is a php file, the file will be downloaded, rather than being executed.

At first I realised that the files in the document root weren't executable, but that didn't help.
I've checked the php config for the location of the socket file, which is as it appears in the config files below.
I had originally wanted to split the config file into smaller peices, but I got persistent errors when testing the config with `nginx -t`.
Have I included my files in the wrong place ? should they all be in the nginx.conf file (and not sitting in the relab.conf file?) ~ although placing them into the nginx.conf file just gave errors about items being double declared, and as they where for the worpress site it made sense in my mind to leave them within the site specific config file.
Is there a way to output the details of the files that are being included, so as I can be sure that I have missed a config file.

The system is running debian : `Linux reslab 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have installed php and nginx, and both are running

php :

```bash
sudo service php7.4-fpm status
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-04 13:34:06 CEST; 7s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 434953 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 74 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 434950 (php-fpm7.4)
     Status: "Ready to handle connections"
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 43238)
     Memory: 9.8M
        CPU: 56ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/php7.4-fpm.service
             ├─434950 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
             ├─434951 php-fpm: pool www
             └─434952 php-fpm: pool www
```

nginx :

```bash
sudo service nginx status
[sudo] password for davem: 
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-04 12:08:34 CEST; 1h 51min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 425978 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 425979 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 425980 (nginx)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 43238)
     Memory: 11.7M
        CPU: 73ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─425980 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─425981 nginx: worker process
             ├─425982 nginx: worker process
             ├─425983 nginx: worker process
             ├─425984 nginx: worker process
             ├─425985 nginx: worker process
             ├─425986 nginx: worker process
             ├─425987 nginx: worker process
             ├─425988 nginx: worker process
             ├─425989 nginx: worker process
             ├─425990 nginx: worker process
             ├─425991 nginx: worker process
             └─425992 nginx: worker process
```

**Setup**

I intend for the main site to be named as for the server, this is its nginx config.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```bash
sudo more nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

#######################################################
### Config for Wordpress multi sites      ########
#######################################################

worker_cpu_affinity auto; #worpress

        ##
        # For Virtual Host Configs
        ##

#        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf; # I do this later on ...


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    # it may be internal, but I want to set up good practice
    # internal pages using a self signed certificate
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    #error log levels are : warn, error crit, alert, and emerg
    # just add one to the end of the below line before the ';'
    # eg    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


    #for the inclusion of other sites config files
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

# for wordpress to use php
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
    upstream php {
                #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }


# below is for gitlab config that cannot be in the main server section.

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket fail_timeout=0;
 }

}
```

**sites-enabled**

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reslab.conf :

```bash
# This will be our default landing page configuration
# All the sub sites, and this one, are using wordpress
# the exception is the gitlab subdomain

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    ## Strong SSL Security
    ## see https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html & https://cipherli.st/
    # ssl on; # this line is deprecated and replaced by the listen 0.0.0.0:443 directive above (just after the start of the server section)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/reslab.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/reslab.key;

    #Some extra ssl wordpress stuff

    # Set caches, protocols, and accepted ciphers. This config will merit an A+ SSL Labs score as of Sept 2015.
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5';

    # Enable HSTS. This forces SSL on clients that respect it, most modern browsers. The includeSubDomains flag is optional.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

#document root for the main langing page
    root /var/www/reslab/wordpress;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    #ensure that all the sub server are considered equally using the '.reslab'
    server_name 10.69.60.18  reslab .reslab *.reslab;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    #add specific logging for this server.
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reslab_access.log;
    #set to debug whilst troubleshooting php problems
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reslab_error.log debug;


}

    #set the mapping of this site to its relevant blog pages
    # this needs to be outside of the server block (but in the http block)
    map $http_host $blogid {
        default       -999;
 
        #Ref: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/
        #include /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nginx-helper/map.conf ;
 
    }


#here is the wordpress specific stuff, that should be copied into most subdomains.
#remember to modify as required the server root if you have just made a simple copy of this file

server {
location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
 
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
 
        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
        }
 

    # load the nginx php / fastCGI support module
    include /etc/nginx/fcgiwrap.conf;

    # this is required to tell nginx to run php files on the server not as a downloadable file !
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # lots of the lines below can be included in the following file(s)
                include fastcgi.conf;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                # the fastci_index is included via the snippets/fastcgi_php.conf file so is not needed here
               # the line is left here for reference
               #fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;

        # can run php through a file socket or via an ip
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

        }
 
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

 #WPMU Files
        location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
                try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/$uri /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 ;
                access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
        }
 
    #WPMU x-sendfile to avoid php readfile()
    location ^~ /blogs.dir {
        internal;
        alias /var/www/example.com/htdocs/wp-content/blogs.dir;
        access_log off;     log_not_found off;      expires max;
    }
 

# ensure that no one is able to write directly to the server from the web page.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #add some rules for static content expiry-headers here


}
```

/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf

```bash
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params  (which is exactly the same as fastcgi.conf ? do I need both ?)

```bash
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf

```bash
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
# we do this in the sites config file, so no need for duplication
#try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;

#this looks back at the earlier file, does this circular reference cause a problem ?
include fastcgi.conf;
```

`/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` has not been modified from the installed version, and as its rather large, with the exception of the line

`cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`

where some guides suggest this should be 0 (zero) and nginx suggest 1, I've tried both values ... and no difference.

Does nginx need a special module to run php to function ?

the file will be downloaded, it makes no difference if I access it from localhost or via its IP address.

Is there something obvious that I am missing ?

I can run the a simpl phpinfo() call from the cli, and I get the expected output.

need more config details... feel free to ask.

thanks in advance

Dave

**edit 1**

So I've tried all the variations of listen and server_name within the server block that has the php details within it.

I have turned on debug logging in the error file for this site, looking through it states `http script var: "/wp-admin/install.php"` which seems like it is seeing it as a php script, and demonstrates that it is clearly capturing the correct file. I have also tried with a basic info.php file... here is a section of the log ...

```bash
try files handler
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 http script var: "/info.php"
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 trying to use file: "/info.php" "/var/www/reslab/wordpress/info.php"
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 try file uri: "/info.php"
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 generic phase: 13
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 content phase: 14
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 content phase: 15
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 content phase: 16
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 content phase: 17
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 content phase: 18
2021/10/04 16:21:17 [debug] 452491#452491: *3 http filename: "/var/www/reslab/wordpress/info.php"
```

I feel there should be some clue in here with the server telling me it is recognised as an `http script` rather than a fastcgi script ?

**edit 2**

So I just logged onto the server, and ran firefox locally. As I expected it attempts to download the file. However it wants to 'open' it in firefox ... when I do this, it just re-downloads ....

However, when I select the 'other' option from the download list the next windows has a message of :

> no applications fournd for `application/octet-stream` files.

which strikes me as firefox trying to tell me that this is an 'application', or am I missunderstanding FFXs message ?

Also when I do the same thing on my remote pc, I still get the 'open with geany' option.

**edit 3**

So it occured to me this may be a permissions issue. So I ran the info.php script from the terminal as the www-data (user and group) :

> `sudo su -s /bin/bash -c "php info.php" -g www-data www-data`

and I got the expected output.

**note** when I did this logged in via ssh to the server.

My other feeling is that the includes aren't correct in some way ? is there a way to debug the files that are being inlcuded (something like `nginx -t` but with a more verbose output ?)

Comment: @virullius : that is a fair point. The site works fine as a flat html, the SSL stuff works just as is should (ive included it for completeness), and the supplemental lies are all those that are required for a wordpress site, I agree that the files have a fair number of lines, and I have included all the supplemental files (just in case they are where the problem lies). Honestly though, there aren't that many lines in either of the main config files, I just have a lot of comments (that maybe I should have removed)

Comment: 2 votes to close this question ! OK so the config files are rather large ... but you would have just asked for them anyway ! I've seen this issue come up a lot in the past, but nothing recent. The other have all been using version of php-fpm that are version 5 or older, and the same for nginx (they all date to around 2016 or earlier). I've looked at a lot of them (maybe all of them !) . I you want me to add details then please just ask.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is far too much config to trouble shoot for a simple problem, it would be far easier to whittle it down to a minimal config that works and then add in other site, caching, whatever.

But on a quick scan, the server block that does the fastcgi_pass has no listen directive, so there would be no way to hit that config.

Also:

Q: "Does nginx need a special module to run php to function ?"

A: No, not specifically for php. FastCGI is the module your using to contact php via standard protocol.

Comment: That seemed so simple .... but didn't help ! I tried the following : listen 127.0.0.1:80 and listen 127.0.0.1:443, listen [::]:80, listen [::]:443, listen 80, listen 443.
It does raise the next question, should every server block have a listen directive? maybe I've missed this somewhere else ?

Comment: Different server blocks need to listen on different ports OR use server_name directive to differentiate them and respond to the Host name in the request. This is referred to as Virtual Hosting. Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: So I added the server_name _ as a catch all .... and still no php love happening on my server.

Comment: I've added in an edit to the original, please have a look

Comment: @DaveM add current version of nginx config which does not work, so we can see where is the mistake. Btw did you restart nginx, cleared browser cache? As written here 
 https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/29/wordpress-nginx-config/ chrome downloads even after changing nginx config, at least in that written case. It downloads from cache even inf nginx is not started.

Comment: @Darius.V : So this is my current nginx.conf, any changes I have made have been in the sites-available/reslab.conf file (and I have mentioned any modifications to them in my edits). I'm using firefox (not chrome, but something to remember !), I've cleared the cache, deleted SSL certificates (just to be sure). Tried a 'private' browser (TOR), but that didn't help either! I try to remember to restart both nginx and php-fpm service after any modifications, but I admit I sometimes forget. I also do nginx -t, could there be a problem in the order of the includes ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why do you change nginx.conf, I usually don't do that. I edit configs in sites available:

Maybe you should try my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Then in sites_available place the config from my blog:

```
server {

    # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04
    listen 80;
    server_name wordpress.darius;
    root /home/darius/Private/Projects/wordpress;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {

      # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-20-04#prerequisites
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
      # end https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-20-04#prerequisites

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    # end https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04

    # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-20-04#prerequisites
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    #end https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-20-04#prerequisites

}
```

In fastcgi.conf the difference I see that in your file there is

```
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
```

but in my there is no such line. Same with /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

There are little differences from your in fastcgi-php.conf, my file looks like this:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Also I am not changing this file ever I think.

cgi.fix_pathinfo in my case is On.

Not sure if there can be problem with the order of includes, since I do not modify those configs, besides ones in sites-available dir.

So try with my configs. And then if that works, make changes little by little to match your needs. Then you should find exactly which part makes it not work.

As you can see I use php 8 so I reccomend it to you also, or change values in my configs examples.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it now. I'm like you I don't really modify the nginx.conf file. The changes that are in there are required for gitlab, which I have temprarily removed from site-enabled so as to be sure I was only seeing the problem site.
I'll have a go with your config and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Those changes for gitlab cannot really be in sites_available configs? I think it should work by adding to sites_avaliable  https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block

Comment: re gitlab, that is a fair point. I've commented that part out for now.
I've also commented out all the peices that you have not included in your file(s), and made sure that all the details are in the same order.
I continue to have the problem... php files are being downloaded?
Not sure where to go from here ?? I've turned on debug logging on all my logs, and there is nothing related to not finding files, or scripts being bad ... I'm going to restart the server ... just for the sake of it !

Comment: @DaveM - can you place minimal version of your project that reproduces the problem on github for example? Including those nginx configs. Otherwise it is hard to see. Maybe I or somebody will try to reproduce locally and then maybe fix will come up.

Comment: I can organise to do that... minimal version may be a little bit of work... What extra config files (those outside of nginx / php) would you like to have ? I'll get onto it when I get home tonight. It will probably start as all the files, before I start to strip it down ... although that said, there isn't much that I have done to the actual web pages.
I'm about to try with apache, as I really need this to be working by now.

Comment: Just for information... I shutdown nginx, installed apache and the libapache-mod-php, navigated to my php page and  .... it works !
I'm completely flummoxed ! Honestly I was at the point where I was beginning to question the server architecture !